# Error Loading Sharepoint List form

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, microsoft

I have a Sharepoint list customized in InfoPath. Everything looks good except that when I edit some of the items. I get this error "There has been an error while loading the form. Click Try again to attempt to load the form again. If this error persists, contact the support team for the Web site." and when I click on the error details. It says "Correlation ID:64cbc69f-e085-0000-ae0d-225d30b72104". Does anyone know what might be the cause? The error doesn't apply to all items in the list. Only for the few ones.

Answer (score 0):

For Correlation ID, please use ULS viewer to get more clues:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/how-to-use-uls-viewer-in-sharepoint-to-analyse-errors.html

Re-pulish the list form to compare the result.